# confunsion regarding a problem with refraction of light

Tags: calculus

I have the following situation. Given points $a$ and $b$, and assuming the surface of the glass to be $x_2 = 0$. How can I formulate an optimization problem whose solution is point $x = (x_1,x_2)$ on the surface of the glass at which light ray enters the glass in going from a to b. Im having trouble understanding the question since I dont know what I want to optimize. I think the problem is not clear. Do they want the point $(x_1,x_2)$ for which light ray takes least time in going from a to b?

[image]

Comment: You can do it with function of one variable and two variable also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** A light ray from $A$ in an environment moves with speed $v_a$ enters the environment with speed $v_g$, elapse time will be
‎$$T=t_1+t_2=\frac{AP}{v_a}+\frac{PB}{v_g}$$‎
refer to figure
‎$$T(x)=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}{v_a}+\frac{\sqrt{b^2+(c-x)^2}}{v_g}$$‎
we have to optimize this . . .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can either use Fermat's principle to minimize time and establish Snell's Law

or else

Use a ready made the result, the Snell's Law:

$$ \dfrac {\sin \alpha}{\sin \beta} = \mu$$

Using $y$ for  $x_2$and $ \mu $ for refractive index ( must be given) and

letting

$$  A (x_a,y_a),\, B (x_b,y_b),\,(x,0)$$

is point of ray impingement that needs to be found.

$$ \dfrac{y_a}{\sqrt{(x_a-x)^2+y_a^2)}} = \dfrac{y_b}{\sqrt{(x_b-x)^2+y_b^2)}}\cdot \mu $$

Hope you can solve out $x$ from this.